# Why is it recommended to avoid java-bean style be used to create domain objects?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

I've been doing some reading and thinking about the ways domain objects are created.

Specifically, from this reading:

[Avoid JavaBeans style of construction](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=668149FCCDBB5F69C772F48407E5B0B1?Id=84)

I agree with most of the author's reasoning.

However, without setters, you may end up with code like:

```
Book book = new Book("title", "author name", isbn, num_pages, blah, blah, blah);
```

In a real project, you can imagine the long list of parameters in the constructor, and the confused programmer who uses it.

Btw, what item 1 in `Effective Java` suggests (`consider static factory methods instead of constructors`) does not quite apply, if you have many domain objects, and you want a simple solution.

So, what is the recommended way to create domain objects?

---

(the question is not specific to Java; comments from other languages are also welcomed)

Comment: I changed your title a bit to steer away from an opinion-based question.

Comment: It is more confusing to me to be presented with a JavaBean full of setters - I never know what attributes are required, and which are not!  At least with constructor arguments, I know that the objects is in a valid state.  If a class requires a dependency, it should in its constructor.  One strategy to cut down on constructor arguments in class decomposition.

Comment: If it's confusing for a developer and you don't want to remember the list of arguments, or there are many possible valid ways to construct the instance, you can use the Builder pattern.

Comment: @jrahhali by "class decomposition", do you mean extracting some fields into its own class?

Comment: @AlexanderLanger ok, but does it need to be done for each domain object class? is there an "abstract builder pattern", so that the builder pattern only needs to be created once?

Comment: of course not.  But usually objects don't have lengthy argument lists.  Overlong argument lists to your constructors *could* be a sign of a code smell, maybe there is one objects where there better be two or three.

Comment: @JeffShaw Yes, extracting related fields into their own class.  For a trivial example, lastName and firstName into a Name class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that a domain object should not be allowed to exist if it is in an invalid state according to your business logic.

So based on that, you have to set the `Book`'s author's name at construction because an authorless book doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, you could set the `dateSold` (that's all I could come up with...) property only through a setter and not at construction because it can still be on the store's shelves and yet be a perfectly valid `Book`.

It can create some pretty verbose constructors indeed, but the benefit is that you know for sure that your object is in a coherent state at all times.